# android EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS issues

Tags: android, android-widget

There is a problem about android . I think the developers would know `"AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS"`, it is the problem, when I got `"AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS"`
like `"intent.getExtras().getIntArray(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS)"`, the result show  that  `"AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS"` is `NULL`.

Who can tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your question to get understood and have people to spend time answering you should invest a bit more time in formatting your question and providing more detail!

That aside:

in onReceive() try:

```
int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

in onUpdate() you get the list of ids already as the parameter!

Comment: OK, appreciate for telling me .

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is a valid answer. There is a difference between EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID and EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS. He is asking about EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS which have a different purpose. Another way to get the id's in the onreceive is int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, myWidget.class)); but regardless of that, the original problem shouldn't return a null.